# how can find RegAsm.exe in all windows platforms (win7, win8, win10 and windows Server 2008, windows server 2016 etc

Tags: .net, batch-file

I would like to search if exists `RegAsm.exe` especially `.net 4 framework` and I search in this path:

```
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\RegAsm.exe
```

1. Is this path correct for all windows (Windows 7, 8, 8.1 and 10)
   and Servers Versions 2008, 2016, etc?
2. It is better to use  `%SystemRoot%` or is the same thing?
3. It is necessary to look for x64 paths?

Comment: Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 are end of life. For all others, .NET Framework 4.x is built in, so you can use that path hardcoded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge the path is fixed. I've never seen it elsewhere, and I'm not sure that an end user is given the opportunity to to modify/choose its location.

However, in addition to the answer already provided, *which searches the filesystem*, you could also check the registry, and set variables accordingly:

```batch-file
@For /F Tokens^=2* %%G In ('""%__APPDIR__%reg.exe" Query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UserData" /S /F "RegAsm.exe" /D 2>NUL|"%__APPDIR__%find.exe" "\v4.""')Do @Echo("%%H"|"%__APPDIR__%find.exe" "4\">NUL&&(Set "RegAsm64=%%H")||Set "RegAsm32=%%H"
```

If you want to see what has been defined you could add `@Set RegAsm` to the next line. Then to use the appropriate version, use either `"%RegAsm64%"` or `"%RegAsm32%"` as needed. It would also be prudent to precede the command with `@For /F Delims^== %%G In ('Set RegAsm 2^>NUL')Do @Set "%%G="`, which would ensure that there's no existing variable is defined, before you start, as this could leave you with a different result.

Example:

```batch-file
@For /F Delims^== %%G In ('Set RegAsm 2^>NUL')Do @Set "%%G="
@For /F Tokens^=2* %%G In ('""%__APPDIR__%reg.exe" Query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UserData" /S /F "RegAsm.exe" /D 2>NUL|"%__APPDIR__%find.exe" "\v4.""')Do @Echo("%%H"|"%__APPDIR__%find.exe" "4\">NUL&&(Set "RegAsm64=%%H")||Set "RegAsm32=%%H"
@Set RegAsm
@Pause
```

I have added the last line, just to give you the opportunity to read any output, *if not running the script directly from the Command Prompt.*

Comment: Ok , after many tries. Better way is to make this with inno setup or nsis or etc.... url for https://jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php . And not with batch files or powershell scripts.

Answer (score 2):

`

You can use **[`where.exe`](https://www.petri.com/using-where-exe)** for find files...

This is an example of how you can search for an executable file and save it in a variable:

---

```bat
@echo off && setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /f tokens^=* %%i in ('%__APPDIR__%where.exe /r "%systemroot%\Microsoft.NET" "RegAsm.exe"
')do call set /a "_cnt+=1+0" && call set "_RegAsm_!_cnt!=%%~i"

if /i defined _RegAsm_1 ( for /L %%L in (1 1 !_cnt!)do echo/!_RegAsm_%%~L!
  ) else echo/ File "RegAsm.exe" not found^!!

rem :: do more task from here... 

endlocal && goto :EOF
```

---

- Outputs:

```bat
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\RegAsm.exe
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\RegAsm.exe
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\RegAsm.exe
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\RegAsm.exe
```

---

- To separate x64/x86:

```bat
@echo off && setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /f tokens^=* %%i in ('%__APPDIR__%where.exe /r "%systemroot%\Microsoft.NET" "RegAsm.exe"
')do call set /a "_cnt+=1+0" && call set "_RegAsm_!_cnt!=%%~i"

if /i defined _RegAsm_1 (for /L %%L in (1 1 !_cnt!
  )do echo/!_RegAsm_%%~L!|%__APPDIR__%find.exe /v "64" >nul && (
    echo/ Path to RegAsm.exe x86: !_RegAsm_%%~L!
    ) || echo/ Path to RegAsm.exe x64: !_RegAsm_%%~L!
  ) else echo/ File "RegAsm.exe" not found^!!

rem :: do more task from here... 

endlocal && goto :EOF
```

---

- Outputs:

```bat
 Path to RegAsm.exe x86: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\RegAsm.exe
 Path to RegAsm.exe x86: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\RegAsm.exe
 Path to RegAsm.exe x64: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\RegAsm.exe
 Path to RegAsm.exe x64: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\RegAsm.exe
```

---

- To find only v4 and x64, add: findstr : **`%__APPDIR__%findstr.exe /lic:"k64\v4\."`**

```bat
@echo off 
2>nul >nul ( for /f tokens^=* %%i in (
'%__APPDIR__%where.exe /r "%systemroot%\Microsoft.NET" "RegAsm.exe"^|%__APPDIR__%findstr.exe /lic:"k64\v4\."'
)do set "_RegAsm=%%~i" ) & if defined _RegAsm call echo/ %_RegAsm
```

---

- Outputs:

```bat
 C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\RegAsm.exe
```

---

- To find only v4 and x86, add: **`%__APPDIR__%findstr.exe /lic:"k\v4\."`**

```bat
@echo off 
2>nul >nul ( for /f tokens^=* %%i in (
'%__APPDIR__%where.exe /r "%systemroot%\Microsoft.NET" "RegAsm.exe"^|%__APPDIR__%findstr.exe /lic:"k\v4\."'
)do set "_RegAsm=%%~i" ) & if defined _RegAsm call echo/ %_RegAsm
```

---

- Outputs:

```bat
 C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\RegAsm.exe
```

---

- For to find and save if exist x86 and x64 variables: **`!_RegAsm_x86!`** and  **`!_RegAsm_x64!`**

```bat
@echo off && setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
2>nul >nul ( for /f tokens^=* %%i in (
'%__APPDIR__%where.exe /r "%systemroot%\Microsoft.NET" "RegAsm.exe"^|%__APPDIR__%findstr.exe /lic:"v4\."'
)do echo/%%i|%__APPDIR__%find.exe "k64" >nul && (set "_RegAsm_x64=%%~i") || set "_RegAsm_x86=%%~i" )

for %%x in (86,64)do echo/ !_RegAsm_x%%~x!

rem :: do more task from here...
```

---

- Outputs:

```bat
 C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\RegAsm.exe
 C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\RegAsm.exe
```

---

Comment: +1, for your efforts. _I've added a registry version too! which like yours, assumes the location will always be within a specifically named grandparent directory._